# Cygwin with CodeBlocks debugger error

Tags: gdb, cygwin, codeblocks

I have Code Blocks 12.11 and I have Cygwin 1.7.27 installed. I have configured C::B to run the Cygwin compiler and it works, but when I try to run the debugger from the Code Blocks environment I get the error:

> Cannot open file /cygdrive/c/some_path/main.c
>
> At /cygdrive/c/some_path/main.c:15

If I try to run gdb on the same file from the cygwin command line interface, it works.

Can somebody please help me fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to make it work is adding a string value under

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Cygnus Solutions\Cygwin\mounts v2
>
> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Cygnus Solutions\Cygwin\mounts v2

with

> name = **cygdrive prefix**
>
> value = **/cygdrive**

If the folders do not exist you have to create them manually.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and this fix does not work if Cygwin is installed separately and then Code::Blocks is installed later.

I am using Code::Blocks version 13.12 and GDB version 7.6.5.

Comment: Well, I cannot help you there. I had a different version of code blocks and it was installed before cygwin.